# facebook send dialog return

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Any way to capture activities on send dialog ?

1. what message is being sent?
2. to whom?
3. user has clicked "send" or "cancel"

I was checking return parameter of facebook send dialog, but could not locate it.

Thanks in adv.

Raxit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Facebook Send dialog is very limited. According to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/
you can not see what message was sent nor to whom. The only thing in the callback parameter is a value which can be null (Cancel hit) or an empty Array (in Chrome and Firefox) indicating something was sent.